# Показать определённый текст из json с помощью php

Tags: php, json

Есть вот такой json файл в из которого я хочу достать `"id":3642592,` и "name":"Schwifty Studios", но не могу понять как это сделать так чтобы просто показывало `3642592 Schwifty Studios`

```
{"data":[{"group":{"id":3642592,"name":"Schwifty Studios","memberCount":1107031,"hasVerifiedBadge":false},"role":{"id":28083340,"name":"Fans","rank":1}}]}
```

Comment: какие **конкретно** сложности?  перевсти json в массив и достать из массива данные - это сложно?)

Comment: да, для меня это сложно

Comment: какой конкретно момент? сколько книг по php вы прочитали перед тем как писать код?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте таким образом:

```
$result = json_decode($json);

foreach($result->data as $item) {
    echo "{$item->group->id} {$item->group->name}";
}
```

Ну или если вы уверены что в json только один элемент:

```
$result = json_decode($json, true);

$id = $result['data'][0]['group']['id'];
$name = $result['data'][0]['group']['name'];

echo "{$id} {$name}";
```